# Glib: Can I reuse a pointer queued to be freed with g_test_queue_free?

Tags: c, linux, unit-testing, pointers, glib

Using Glib Testing framework, I would like to know if I can reuse a pointer queued to be freed with g_test_queue_free?

Here's a code sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
static void some_test()
{
  gchar* tmp;

  tmp = func_returning_gchar_ptr (...params...);
  g_assert(tmp);
  g_test_queue_free(tmp);

  tmp = func_returning_gchar_ptr (...params...);
  g_assert(tmp);
  g_test_queue_free(tmp);

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that should be fine